# TYPO3 7.6 backend doesn't show startdate enddate of fluidcontent

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x

We migrated an older TYPO3 site from 6.x to 7.6. One of the last things which don't work is that all be-users (inclusive admins) don't see the options startdate and enddate in the access tab of an element. This bug/feature affects only fluid content elements. On the same page are normal text elements, which are fine.

I already checked the user-rights, `localconf.php`, `ext_tables.php` and I searched for `TCE.tt_content`-configs but I couldn't find something irregular. In the rights management these element are not listed under "allowed exclusion fields". Do you have some ideas, hints?!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to inspect the TCA.
The TCA defines which fields are shown in the edit mask.This can be done field wise or in palettes.
I assume the startdate/enddate fields are in a palette and that the palette changed from TYPO3 6 to TYPO3 7 (name, contained fields, ...).
As long as your TCA is not adapted to this changes these fields are not visible.

Answer (score 0):

Did you run the Database analyzyer? All Steps in the Upgrade Wizard are completed? For a full migration from css_styled_content to fluid_styled_content you have to run the Upgrade Wizard too.

1. install fluid_styled_content
2. uninstall css_styled_content
3. run Upgrade Wizard